# Layout of multichannel 20-bit DACs

Tags: analog, emc, dac, layout, emi-filtering

I've been reading various app notes as well as Ott trying to figure out how to lay out multiple converters on a board. Most explain how to route the data lines but not much about routing the power supply or reference. Ott mentions layout A for multiple converters. This makes sense for the data lines but this would seem to mix up the reference and data lines. Layout B doesn't partition the ground plane and just passes the reference around in the analog half of the board. This seems to make more sense to me but Ott mentions that some partitioning might be helpful when using converters with bit depths beyond 16-bits. He also mentions stripline, which appeals to the microwave designer in me, but this will be the first run of a board and it would be helpful to be able to cut and bodge traces. Any suggestions? 20-bits takes some serious discipline I reckon so any help is appreciated.

**The pink trace corresponds to a bus of kelvin connections back to the DAC. It is not a single wire. The orange wire corresponds to the entire SPI bus. It, too, is not a single wire. The DAC symbol is not just the DAC IC, it is a symbol inclusive of the DAC, and supporting hardware including but not limited to its reference buffers necessary to make the Kelvin connection.**

[image: Proposed layouts]

Comment: What DAC is it? Post a link to the data sheet please.

Comment: The one and only AD5791 https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad5791.pdf

Comment: What reference voltages are you using? How stable are they? How noise free are they?

Comment: an Analog Devices EV-LTZ1000-REFZ board, which features an LTZ1000A and a +/- 5 volt output, each stable to better than 1 PPM.

Comment: Specifically, the LTZ1000A has 200 ppb noise from 0.1 Hz to 10 Hz, above that I reckon we're above the 1/f knee and the integrated noise power is dominated by this region. Long term stability is 2 uV/rt-kHr. Over a week this is 56 nV or 8 ppb.

Comment: It would be better with a +/- 10 volt reference. Is there a demo board for said device? If so, then take a look at its documentation to see how they laid out the PCB.

Comment: Demo board has one channel and thus avoids the layout-specific questions asked in my submission.

Comment: *kelvin connections back to the DAC* - I don't understand that bit - do you mean back to each reference (positive and negative)?

Comment: Yes. Reference voltage and ground sense lead. No shared currents.

Comment: There is a third possibility...diagram A but have the DAC slightly away from the bridge so that the REF has space to travel from ADC to ADC on the lower side without intersecting with the digital lines on the top side. Also, should the REF be located on the side like that? Or should it be in the middle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split plane always looks good until you put in those pesky connectors.

[image]

In the split plane case, any common mode current on your voltage output cables will traven through the separate ground pours and will have to find its way through whatever path it can find. This path will not be a copper plane, worst case it could be a trace, and even worse it could be inside one of the chips. So this way of doing things is very vulnerable to common mode current on the cables.

In contrast the continuous ground plane without any splits just shorts any common mode current between the connectors right at the connectors, so it won't go disturb the sensitive analog chips.

Here's how I'd do it:

[image]

If you really like split ground planes, the split should be between the analog and the digital section, and no important component should be over the split (especially not a dac). The DACs, being analog parts, are on the analog side, and the SPI traces cross the split on a bridge of ground plane copper. I've drawn the split as the vertical black bars.

If there is a connector for the micro to talk to the outside world, and you want ppm's, then common mode current through this connector could be a problem. Consider optical isolation.

Then, the output connectors are on the short side of the board, Vref's GND is referenced to output ground due to being closer, etc.

Put VREF in the middle like metacollin says.

Because a kelvin connection has one force node and one sense node, you can't have a kelvin VREF connection to several places. But you can have several kelvin connections. Since the DACs already use this scheme, you can use a dual opamp per DAC, using the provided force/sense pins, but you should wire it as a differential amp so it replicates the difference between the positive and negative terminals of your Vref chip and the positive and negative reference terminals of the DACs.

Comment: +1 this nicely illustrates why ground splits are bad in almost every project. i wouldnt recommend the minimal slits in your second part either: the digital return currents is restricted anyway, and the gaps cause EMI resonances

Comment: Appreciate it! The USB connector will be isolated (GMR isolators...) through a bus-powered ft232.

Comment: Another somewhat off-topic question... what are your thoughts on grounding the BNC connectors to the chassis? How about common mode chokes on the outputs?

Comment: Depends if the chassis is metal or not! If it is plastic, then the ground plane near the connectors is "chassis"... But if it is metal, yes I think you should ground the BNCs to chassis, a thick metal plate will hold all the connector grounds at the same potential which I guess is what you want. But since this ground is also your 0V reference used by the DACs and output opamps, it means the PCB ground plane also has to be connected to chassis at this spot too.

Comment: Perhaps use metal body BNCs that are grounded to the PCB plane, and held onto the face plate with the usual hex nut, something like that. If you use a common mode filter, then that will add impedance in GND, which means GND on all connectors might not be the same after all. So... I dunno. Note I think the USB connector shield still needs a capacitive connection to chassis for EMI.

Answer (score 1):

**Use a solid ground plane.** You can use this ground plane to return all digital signals.

If you are really worried about common-impedance coupling between the analog signals, consider the following:

**How large is the common impedance (usually about 500 µOhm for 1 oz of ground plane or 250 µOhm for 2 oz of ground plane) and what amount of current flows in the common impedance?** If the resulting voltage is tolerable, then don't worry and just use the Ground plane as analog reference point for all analog signals as well.

However, if the common-impedance coupling through the ground plane would be too bad, e.g. more than 10 microvolts, then use two dedicated traces per analog signal, with one line being a dedicated ground trace through which you force the respective return current. Then tie all of these traces to the ground plane at *one* point per trace. This point can - but doesn't have to - be the same point for all traces (i.e. a star point). In general, ground the traces at a point that makes common-impedance coupling with other analog signals negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute number one priority here is to keep the reference lines clean.  Any layout that would require that you route the reference connections across digital lines is not going to give you anything close to 1ppm performance.

I would not go with either A or B, but instead do something like this, which keeps true to the spirit of Ott's plane splitting while allowing access for analog reference lines.  [image]

The noise benefits from the isolated analog planes are not going to be ruined if there is a small easement in between them.

The ground 'easements' are really just to give any stray ground currents somewhere to flow, but if you are using a star ground with each reference having its own trace both to the negative and Vout pins of the voltage reference in a star ground formation, then the small amount of bias current going to the buffers should be contained to those traces.  At 10Khz, ground currents are going to flow in a mostly straight line, and at higher frequencies will concentrate directly under the current that it is the return path for.

As long as you are careful about the rest of the board, there is no reason any ground current should need to flow in between the analog channels.  The main benefit of the isolation between the analog planes is reduction of common mode noise, and cheating a little is not going to significantly impact that.

Plus, you gotta route those traces somehow, right?  And at the end of the day, you ***must*** keep the reference lines out of the digital section and routed such that they are not parallel to any digital lines either, slot or not.

When you really think about these constraints, I think it becomes clear something along this proposed layout is the only solution.  This layout gives you the best you can get without having a dedicated reference for each DAC, in my opinion.

You of course will get the best possible performance by having totally independent references for each channel.  No one said precision was cheap!

But I think you can, with careful component selection and design in regards to the rest of the board, achieve 1ppm performance with this proposed layout.

Comment: I think it’s not a great idea to have closed slots in the ground plane like this — I think it’s mentioned in Ott.